# Access svg icon from static resource zip file

Tags: svg-icon, svg

I have added zip file of lightning design system which contains fonts,icon,images,style folders. in this svg icons are in **icons/utility-sprite/svg** folder, i have set the path but it;s not reflecting on visualforce page.

```
<svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" aria-hidden="true"> 
<use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS080,'/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#alert')}"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: is the static resource loading? any debugging attempts? whats the status code on the resource?

Answer (score 0):

use `<apex:slds />`at top of your vf page and give the reference of icon like this

`<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opportunity">
</use>`

Comment: already added at top. but not working

Comment: After adding you can directly give reference to icon like above still not working?

Comment: no,not working.